# Vue Cypress Component Test Runner - location of test files

Tags: vue.js, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I've added the Cypress Vue Component Test runner to an existing Vue app and I want all the test files to be in the same directory as the components.  However, whatever I put in my cypress.json file seems to be ignored and cypress always wants to look in the default integration folder.

In my cypress.json file I have:

```
{
    "component": {
      "componentFolder": "src",
      "testFiles": "**/*.spec.ts",
      "testMatch": [
        "**/src/**/*.spec.[jt]s?(x)"
      ]
    },
}
```

but when I run

```
npm run cy:run:chrome
```

I get:

```
> vue-myapp@0.1.0 cy:run:chrome
> cypress run --browser chrome

Can't run because no spec files were found.

We searched for any files inside of this folder:

/Users/richardshergold/Projects/vue-myapp/cypress/integration
```

Comment: I found that running npx cypress open-ct solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [change the default folder](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders-Files) that Cypress looks in for tests using `integrationFolder` in your `cypress.json`. This value defaults to `cypress/integration`.

Even when adding a `testFiles` field, Cypress will restrict that search to the `integrationFolder` value.

```js
...
"integrationFolder": "/path/to/tests/folder",
...
```